# Can't move files on cifs mount with 'mv'

Tags: mount, cifs, smb

Unfortunately I can't move any files within my mounted Windows Server 2016 SMB share.

**Working:**

Creating files/directories
Delete files/directories
Read files/directories
Write to files/directories

**Not working:**

Move files with `mv` command

```
# ll
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 USERNAME USERNAME    0 Mar 26 11:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Mar 23 14:06 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 USERNAME USERNAME    0 Mar 26 11:01 file1


# mv file1 file2
mv: cannot move 'file1' to 'file2': No such file or directory
```

**mount options:**

```
vers=3.0,rw,credentials=/home/USERNAME/.smbcredentials,nosetuids,noperm,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -lb`. I guess your filename has special characters in it which the `-b` flag would reveal.

Comment: # ls -lb  
total 0  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 USERNAME USERNAME 0 Mar 26 11:01 file1